Does google-services.json file change when the project's environment type is changed to production?
I am having problems with push notification. When I use the app on development everything was working fine. After I released my app, users do not receive the notifications anymore.
I looked through all my codes and did exactly what the documentation says but did not change the fact that users do not receive the notifications.
